# iphone app for remember username and password

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

is any examples out there for iphone app remember me option using coredata..

Comment: What version of ios are you thinking seeing as there are different storage options. Well afaik as i'm only just starting out myself :)

Comment: You should notbe storing passwords in core data objects unless you are first encrypting them.  See nicktmro's answer for a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Keychain Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html) and yes, there is example code on the site.

> Computer users typically have to manage multiple accounts that require logins with user IDs and passwords. Secure FTP servers, AppleShare servers, database servers, secure websites, instant messaging accounts, and many other services require authentication before they can be used. Users often respond to this situation by making up very simple, easily remembered passwords, by using the same password over and over, or by writing passwords down where they can be easily found. Any of these cases compromises security.
>
> The Keychain Services API provides a solution to this problem. By making a single call to this API, an application can store login information on a keychain where the application can retrieve the information—also with a single call—when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to store the username and password of a user? If so would it now be worth storing them into a  dictionary and saving the dictionary to the document's directory? If you are storing user credentials it maybe worth encrypting them before saving them.